# How do I remove a misspelled word that I accidentally taught to my phone?

Tags: keyboard, autocorrect, dictionary

The autocorrect has the ability to learn new words, and I accidentally taught it a fake word. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the Settings app > Keyboard > Typing Settings and there will be a button to reset the dictionary. Note that this will delete **all** custom words. There is no way to delete a single word.

Comment: Is this still the case? I've been away from WP for a while, but hope to come back if there's a Lumia 930 for AT&T.